# Why top & bottom margins are Not apply? And Why left margin apply?

Tags: html, css

Please tell that in following html & css Snippet: -

**Html:**

```
<p>Paragraph Text</p>
    <p>
        <a class="cta" href="#">Visit Blog</a>
    </p>
<p>Paragraph Text</p>
```

**Css:**

```
a.cta  {
   font-size:18px;
   margin-top: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 40px;
}​
```

​1) Why the **top & bottom margins are Not apply** To the **anchor's "cta"** Class?.
and
2) Why the left margin is apply without any problem?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `display: inline-block;` to your CSS

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v413hav/Rvwep/)

CSS

```
a.cta  {    
    font-size:18px;    
    margin-top: 50px;    
    margin-bottom: 50px;    
    margin-left: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Explanation: Because `<a>` is an `inline` element, inline elements doesn't take top, bottom margins, you need to make it block level element, by declaring `inline-block` or `block`

[List](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/inline.html) of inline and block level elements

Comment: You _can_ get some odd behavior with `inline-block` in older versions of IE, but it's pretty safe to use with anchor tags. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

The `a` element by default is an "inline" element. Meaning that it shows up in the same line as the text around it. By definition, inline elements do not have top or bottom margins, only left and right. To add a top or bottom margin, simply declare the element as a "block" type element by modifying your CSS as shown below:

```
a.cta  {
   display: block;
   font-size:18px;
   margin-top: 50px;
   margin-bottom: 50px;
   margin-left: 40px;
}​
```

However, you need to be aware that changing it from an inline element to a block element does have some consequences. For example, the text in the `a` tag will be displayed in its own section below the text before it. And any text after it will be shown in a separate section below it, as though they were all part of a separate paragraph.

Comment: But using `inline-block` wont make the paragraph break :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the parent element of a.cta a width and height for the margin to take effect. Margin doesn't mean much to your browser without a point of reference to work with.

p{width:100px;height:100px;}

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to apply the class to the `<p>` element instead of the `<a>`. I don't know if that will work for what you're trying to do, but it does give you the margins you're looking for without having to specify width.

**HTML**:

```
<p>Paragraph Text</p>
<p class="cta">
    <a href="#">Visit Blog</a>
</p>
<p>Paragraph Text</p>​
```

**CSS**:

```
p.cta  {
font-size:18px;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
margin-left: 40px;
}​
```

And [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/d3EcA/5/).

-Marcatectura